# Taking suitable odd power of $\phi$, to get order of $\phi$ a power of $2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $\phi\in Aut(G)$, for a finite group $G$. We also have $\phi^2\in Inn(G)$. Therefore it is clear that if we can prove that $\phi^m\in Inn(G)$ for any odd $m$, then because $\phi^2$ is inner, it implies that $\phi$ is also inner.

Now in a  proof I was doing, author wanted to assume order of $\phi$ to be a power of $2$ for some purpose. Thus he says by taking suitable odd power of $\phi$, we may assume that order of $\phi$ is a power of $2$.

Now suppose I have $\phi$ which has order 10. Now I need to replace my $\phi$ with another $\phi'=\phi^k$ for some odd $k$, such that order of $\phi'$ becomes a power of $2$. Suppose I take $\phi'=\phi^5$, then I am done.

But now if I have $\phi$ which has order $7$, then what do I take my $\phi'$. Why does this work for all orders of $\phi$.

Comment: If $\phi$ has order $7$, then $\phi`=\phi^7$ has order $1=2^0$. Would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If order of $\phi$ is already odd like $7$, notice that $<\phi>=<\phi^2>$. Hence

$\phi^2\in Inn(G)\implies \phi\in Inn(G)$. Thus, you can assume that order of $\phi$ is an even number.